# No startup disk to restart from after closing Disk Utilities screen

Tags: startup, restore

My 15" MacBook Pro starts up and goes to the disk utilities. Following a solution to close the utility window I then see the "Choose Startup Disk" but there isn't a system to choose from so I may click on continue.  I have tried using Disk Utilities to "Reinstall OS X" but when I then click on Continue it jumps to "OS X El Capitan" and I click on Continue and see "To download and restore OS X your computer's eligibility will be verified with Apple". I then choose Continue and after a few seconds I get "An Error occurred while preparing the installation.  If I click OK the Mac jumps back to the OS X Utilities screen.  It is an endless cycle.  I don't know what to do next.

I do not know what state it was in before since I just rediscovered I had it in storage.  I charged it up and here where I am.

Comment: What next is what model of Mac do you have, what state was it in Before? In other words how did it get this way? Show us what disks are in disk utility, if any. If you help us understand, we will help you.